# converting pyd to dll so i could use it in C# wpf

Tags: python, c#, dll, cython, pyd

I made a pretty nice scraping package in py (with **init**.py file and all), and id like to be able to use it without rewriting everything in a c# wpf project.
Id also want to send it later to a friend, which probably doesnt not have python installed, so i cant use stuff like pyconnect.

So I used nukita to get a .pyd file, yet even tho its like a dll i cant seem to import it into my WPF
.net project.
Also tried using Cython but it seems like a mess if i want to export the entire package
what can i do?

Comment: You can also try IronPython - it's a .net-based python implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980619/compile-run-and-import-python-module-in-c-sharp-net